# Rerender text with updated value in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fabricjs

I'm using [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs) and want to render the text every time a value is updated.

But when I do this, the new text overlaps the old. I tried to clear the object but didn't find any way to do so.

Below is the code snippet to describe what I doing:

```
//console.log('topp'+ rect.getTop());
rect.on('moving', function() {
    var rectTop = rect.getTop();
    var upCounter = 0;
    var downCounter = 0;
    var text40;
    var canvas_objects = canvasForRect._objects;
    // console.log('topp'+ rect.getTop());
    // READ STRING FROM LOCAL STORAGE
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('heatMapClickData');
    // CONVERT STRING TO REGULAR JS OBJECT
    var text40;
    var last = canvas_objects[canvas_objects.length - 1];

    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
    $.each(parsedObject, function(index, item) {
        if (rectTop >= item['pos_y']) {
            upCounter += 1;
        } else {
            downCounter += 1;
        }
        text40 = new fabric.Text("Total clicks above line" + upCounter, {
            fontSize: 40
        });

    });
    // var obj = canvasForRect.getActiveObject();
    // console.log(obj);
    text40.set({
        text: "Total clicks above line" + upCounter
    });
    canvasForRect.add(text40);
    // canvas.renderAll();
});
```

How do I re-render the text every time `upCounter` is updated?

Comment: Your are creating new fabric.Text object inside 'moving' event. Your behavior is expected. Please declare your object somewhere outside the 'moving' event and do update of it inside that event.